# Making Firebase Cloud Storage URL Unguessable?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I want a group of users to access files stored in Cloud Storage, but I want to make sure they are authorized. Do the unique ids generated by Firestore  create enough protection to make them unguessable?

I have my files stored using this structure in Firestore:
**/projects/uidOfProject/files/uidOfFile**

I made sure that only authorized users can view **uidOfProject** and **uidOfFile** using Firestore Rules.

I store that actual files in Storage here:
**/projects/uidOfProject/files/uidOfFile**

But, I cannot lock down this path to only the authenticated user id, because other users can access this project.

Is the fact that I have two unique ids enough to prevent a user who doesn't have access from finding these files? What are the odds of a user figuring out both the **uidOfProject** and **uidOfFile** and manipulating that file? Is there a more secure way of doing this? I know cloud functions could offer a solution, but at a cost of speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do the unique ids generated by Firestore create enough protection to
>   make them unguessable?

Security through obscurity is NOT security. Good [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) to read.

Unguessable, probably. However, due to the somewhat public nature of URLs, logfiles, information leaks, "hey check this out" favors, etc. objects that are not properly protected will be discovered.

If only users of the project can access the files, can they also list the files? If yes, curiosity might take place browsing to see what is there.

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not allow traversing folders, so that's why I thought going the unguessable route was safe. That's what they're using now. I'm wondering if using the algorithm they do for unguessable ids I would be safe?

Comment: @EverettGlovier - my first sentence answers your question. From there you just take risks - it is up to you if obscurity is worth the risk.